# how to display all those users on map which are at particular distance away from the current user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation

I want to store user's current location when they log in and display only those users on map which are at a particular distance away from current_user(say 20km).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popular ruby [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries) gem has similar functionality. Please checkout the Ryan's [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?autoplay=true) for detail.